# MegaSync client requires libcrypto++9

Tags: apt, dependencies, packaging, mega

So, I was trying to install the sync client for Mega (http://mega.nz) on my Ubuntu 15.10 install. Yes, I know it's pre-release, but here is my question:
When i install the .dep file, I get that

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 megasync
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of megasync:
 megasync depends on libcrypto++9; however:
  Package libcrypto++9 is not installed.
```

When I then try to install libcrypto++9, I get the following error:

```
E: Package 'libcrypto++9' has no installation candidate
```

It then tells me that `libcrypto++9v5` replaces it, but installing that doesn't satisfy MegaSync.

A quick Google search reveals that the `v5` means "compiled using gcc5". Alas, the library is still the same. Why the new name, and how can I install my .deb file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Ubuntu 15.10 (All Versions)**:

Add this repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ([check here](https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/) for other versions):

`deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_15.10/ ./`

Get/Add the key:

`wget -O - https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_15.10/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Update: `sudo apt-get update`

Install **MEGASync**:

`sudo apt-get install megasync`

For Nautilus plugin:

`sudo apt-get install nautilus-megasync`

Answer (score 0):

either download packages `libcrypto++9` from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid-updates/libcrypto++9) and install it using command :

```
sudo dpkg -i libcrypto++9_5.6.1-6+deb8u1build0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
```

or

it is in universal packages so add `universal` repository if not added and install using command

```
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++9
```

i have tested this in ubuntu 14.04 so `megasync` also depending on `libc-ares2` packages
download it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/libc-ares2/download) and install it using command

```
sudo dpkg -i libc-ares2_1.10.0-2_amd64.deb
```

or

it is available in `main` Ubuntu repository so add if not added and install using command

```
sudo apt-get install libc-ares2
```

then try to install `megasync`

```
sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_15.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been forced AFK. I have `universal` enabled. The problem only exists in ubuntu 15.10 because of the switch to gcc5

Comment: @bpou did you get it fixed? I'm upgrading my 15.04 -> 15.10 and i'm having the same issue. It was there in 15.04 to, but i can't remember how i fixed it.

Comment: I manually edited the dependencies of the deb file.  HOWTO here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=110458

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions I found in the web worked so I tried the following:

I downloaded libcrypto++9 from here, and installed it as a .deb.
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libc/libcrypto++/libcrypto++9_5.6.1-6_amd64.deb

The same for libc6 from:
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-4_amd64.deb

Then I downloaded libqt5gui5-gles_5.15.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb from
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src-gles/libqt5gui5-gles_5.15.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb

You should do it with any package that is missing in your own configuration. I recomend this website to find them: https://pkgs.org/

Comment: This answer can break a system since it not only advises installing software from .deb files, but the answer also suggests installing packages from other distributions. Additionally, pkgs.org is not an official mirror or source for Ubuntu software. When there are official sources like https://packages.ubuntu.com, referring users to unofficial software sources poses an unnecessary risk. This answer also lacks [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), which is needed so the names of packages can be distinguished from the surrounding text.